# How to use Constants.php file in Selenium php test?

Tags: php, selenium, phpstorm

I am trying to create a Constants.php class to store constants for multiple tests within the same project.

**Setup**

Laravel 4 with Selenium

PhpStorm IDE

**Folder Structure for my first test:**

```
Selenium 
- Constants.php
- CriticalTests
- - GrabProductInfoCept.php
```

Contents of Constants.php

```
<?php

class Constants {

// Product Variables
public static $product_to_search = 107049;

// Email Variables
public static $vendor_email = 'EMAIL REMOVED';
public static $affiliate_email = 'EMAIL REMOVED';
```

Contents of GrabProductInfoCept.php

```
<?php

$I = new SeleniumGuy\UserSteps($scenario);
$I->wantTo('can verify product dump information');

// Log In first...
$I->amOnPage('/auth/login');
$I->see('Vendor / Affiliate Login');
$I->successfullyLogin();
$I->see('Your JVZoo Account Overview');

// Grab the product name
$I->amOnPage('/products/edit/' . \Constants::$product_to_search);
$I->see('Add Product Information');
$to_match = $I->grabValueFrom('product_name');

// Get to the right page
$I->amOnPage('/b/p/' . \Constants::$product_to_search .'/2');
$I->see('Order Review:');

$I->fillField('contact_email', \Constants::$vendor_email);
$I->fillField('paypal_email', \Constants::$affiliate_email);
$I->click('paypal_checkout');
$I->see('Your payment summary');

// Grab the paykey
$paykey = $I->grabFromCurrentUrl('/paykey=(.{20})/');

// Now test the transaction dump
$I->amOnPage('transactions/lookup');
$I->see('Transaction Lookup');
$I->fillField('paykey', $paykey);
$I->click('lookup');
$I->see('Transaction:');

// And make sure you've got the right transaction!
$I->see(\Constants::$product_to_search);
$I->see(\Constants::$vendor_email);
$I->see($paykey);
```

**Results:**
The test dies at the first \Constansts::$product_to_search call. What am I doing wrong here? I can't find much documentation on constants files.

Comment: Check PHP's error log for possible messages? Possibly that file was not included yet?

Comment: I have tried to include it this way: `// Grab the product name
include (dir(__FILE__).'../Constants.php');` - but the log file is saying the class cannot be found. EDIT that is on two separate lines and not a commented include

Comment: I would also like to note that PhpStorm autocompleted those variables from \Co on - so at least in PhpStorm's logic, the file is connected properly (and that was before any include call).

Comment: PhpStorm can autocomplete any class regardless of any real include/require statements (these days all classes are usually autoloading) as long as file is within a project (or referenced via include paths etc functionality).

Comment: *"but the log file is saying the class cannot be found."* -- this error is reported by actual PHP interpreter and has no relation to PhpStorm. Most likely that file is still not loaded (or .. maybe you have more than one file with that name and wrong file is loaded -- try specifying FULL absolute path -- at least for testing). **ALSO:** please upload that file on some file sharing site (dropbox etc) and give a link -- maybe there is some problem in actual file (invisible characters etc -- could be the reason -- seen it few times).

Comment: Understood (it was just the first question my boss asked lol). I am very very new to Selenium (this is my second day working on it) - but I havnen't used (and can't find the instructions for) the build command in terminal. Could that possibly be an issue?

Comment: Sorry .. not a Selenium user myself -- cannot help in this regard.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gt3sa9xqxh9dbr5/Constants.php - if I did that correctly.

Comment: I had a look at the class file and found no issues -- it's all latin characters only (unless the one you actually using is different). What I'm thinking -- maybe it's a caching issue in your app? Please check if class is actually loaded (use standard `class_exists()` after `include` line).

Comment: Unfortunately one of my other questions on here has to do with reading outputs with Selenium testing. I can run that method but I have no clue how to see what the method returns (unless it returns in the php log).

Comment: You mean that you do not know how to use `error_log()` (or any custom function that will write some text into custom file) with some `if (class_exists(params_here)` kind of code? The main thing here, that accordingly to **your** words PHP interpreter cannot load that class properly. It's not PhpStorm issue here.

Comment: I have only been coding for 2 years, and only in PHP for 1 year (about, not quite). A lot of this is very new to me and I've only tried writing to a log once, in JAVA, for a class project. So no, I didn't know (or think about) those implementations. I really believe the issue lies in how the class was started (Codeception has some basic terminal commands that I don't know about, but have caught references to in my research). Waiting for someone who knows more about my setup to come along, hopefully with more solid ideas (not that you haven't helped :) ).

Comment: The thing is that there are other classes in use in this overall project that didn't have to be included to be called. Selenium and Codeception have some configuration and inclusion files that I think may have gotten skipped over, but can't find the right resource to help me troubleshoot (or restart, if need be).

Comment: Well -- cannot help you here then -- not a Selenium or Codeception user, unfortunately. But in any case: if you include file and PHP still thinks that it is not loaded ... then something wrong is going on which I'm unable to identify from here.